# Linking windows C++ project to boost on command line architecture type issue

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I have an external c++ code base I am trying to build that requires BOOST.  I have VS2015 community edition and am trying to build from the command line.

I downloaded and built boost using this command:

```
.\b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 --build-type=complete --abbreviate-paths architecture=64 address-model=64 install -j4
```

I then am trying to build the project like this:

```
cl /EHsc -I "C:\Users\alex\Documents\boost_1_60_0" myproj_helper.cpp main.cpp /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Boost\lib" /out:program.exe
```

When I do this I get the following error.

```
libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s-1_60.lib(thread.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

I am not sure if this means I built boost incorrectly and need to rebuild with different settings or if I am missing an argument that I need to give cl regarding the architecture or what.  I am on a windows 10 home 64 bit machine.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building Boost using the architecture `x64`, which is good and what you want. The problem is that you're building your project with the default architecture of `x86` which conflicts with Boost when linking. Using [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx), you can setup your environment in the command line to use the `x64` architecture.

1. Set the desired MSVC version's **VC** directory as the working directory.

   `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"`
2. Run this magic batch script (there's also `amd64_x86` *which is default*, and `amd64_arm`)

   `vcvarsall amd64`

If you intended to build for `x86`, you will just need to configure Boost to build to `x86`. Like I said, this is the default for MSVC which will make it compatible.

Comment: this worked, thank you very much.  The time you saved me is well worth the downvotes I get for a noob question :)